# Tips to install skype on 64bit

Tags: skype

### Dicas para instalar skype no 64bits

Gostaria de instalar o skype 64bits e inicializá-lo junto com o sistema.  Além disto gostaria de deixar links para fazer ligações com atalhos visíveis com imagem

Machine-translation to English:

> ### Tips to install skype on 64bit
>
> I would like to install skype 64bit and initialize it with the system. In addition you want to make links to make calls with visible shortcuts with image.

Comment: English, please.

Comment: (Sé solamente español). Por favor, pregunta en inglés, no en portugues.

Answer (score 0):

For 64-bit version you need to install 32-bit architecture files first.
Launch the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and paste this code.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then run this command.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next download Skype on your Desktop folder.

```
cd /Desktop && sudo wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

Finally double click the Skype installer on your Desktop.Your Ubuntu Software Center will be launched and on the top right corner press the Install button.

If I helped you don't forget to select my answer please.